# Does the Assisi loop heal injuries?

Tags: medical-science, zoology, alternative-medicine

The Assisi loop uses "[Pulsed Electromagnetic Field Therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsed_electromagnetic_field_therapy)" to treat inflammation in animals. This seems like a bunch of woo.

Does this work?

Comment: ... why "Assisi loop"? The article you linked has no mention of "Assisi"...

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly a lot of [peer reviewed literature](https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?q=bone%20repair%20by%20electromagnetic%20fields&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) about it.

[This](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ali_Yadollahpour/publication/265161879_Electromagnetic_Fields_in_the_Treatment_of_Wound_A_Review_of_Current_Techniques_and_Future_Perspective/links/540c2c780cf2df04e750de4f.pdf)<sup>1</sup> literature review's abstract says:

> Electromagnetic fields (EMFs) have shown a promising potential for treatment
>   of different wounds. Different techniques have been proposed for wound treatment
>   including electric current therapy (ET), EMF therapy (EMFT), static magnetic field, and
>   combined magnetic field. The present study reviews the most current EMF based methods
>   for wound treatments and compare their efficiency for each wound. In addition the
>   proposed mechanisms of action of these techniques were reviewed. Among different
>   techniques, ET shows more promising effects on wounds. Furthermore, different
>   parameters influence the therapeutic performance of ET and EMFT including electrical
>   intrinsic properties of living organs as well as physical parameters of stimulations. For
>   further development of EMF based treatments for wound it is necessary to develop more
>   quantitative assessments for wound healing.

<sup>1</sup> Yadollahpour, A., & Jalilifar, M. (2014). Electromagnetic Fields in the Treatment of Wound: A Review of Current Techniques and Future Perspective. J pure appl microbio, 8(4), 2863-77.